# Redirecting batch file output to winform textbox issues

Tags: c#, winforms, batch-file

I created a GUI that calls a batch file and shows the command line output in a textbox after clicking a button. The batch file runs and the output is redirected properly for some time until ~80 lines in and the textbox output suddenly starts displaying the actual code in the batch file. Does this indicate a bug in the batch file or a problem with my script? I don't really know how to start debugging this problem.

I also notice that the batch file I'm calling from the GUI makes calls to other batch files. Could this be causing problems as well?

I should also mention that the batch file successfully runs from the command line.

```
private void buildProg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Process process = new Process())
    {
        process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = some_directory;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "start.bat";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "arg1 arg2";
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.OutputDataReceived += proc_OutputDataReceived;
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    }
}

private void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + e.Data);
    }));
}
```

When I run it from the GUI the batch file seems to be tripping up at this part.

`if exist %version_file_path% ( 
    set /p _version= <%version_file_path% 
) else (
    echo %version_file_path% not found
    pause
)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two things happening here;

1) The `/p` statement is asking for user input, pausing the command and waiting.

2) You're disposing the Process before the events are firing, meaning we wouldn't be able to simulate the input it needs to continue executing.

This pretty much solves it:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;
    }

    Process p;

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        p?.Dispose();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (p != null)
            p.Dispose();

        p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "test.bat";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.OutputDataReceived += proc_OutputDataReceived;
        p.Start();
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
    }

    private void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + e.Data);

        }));

        //can use either of these lines.
        (sender as Process)?.StandardInput.WriteLine();
        //p.StandardInput.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're right it could be some problem with a character... I added the portion of the batch file that its tripping up on. I'm not allowed to modify the batch file so is there some way I can get around this portion while preserving it?

Comment: After reproducing your problem, I can see that it's the `/p` switch that causes the OutputDataReceived event to stop firing.  That's a very curious bug indeed.  I'll update my answer if I can figure it out... but this might be beyond me.

Comment: That did it! Its great to see this working - thanks for the help!!